# How do I return 2 Values from a method?

Tags: java, methods

//So heres my code

```
public static String askQ(String str)
{           
    Scanner M = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(str);
    String ans = M.nextLine();

    return ans;
}
```

//this section of the program is a repeated question method

```
public static int getValues(int First, int Second)
{
    First = Integer.parseInt(askQ("First Number"));
    Second = Integer.parseInt(askQ("Second Number"));

    return First;
    return Second;
```

//i get an error when trying to return second
    }
// this section needs to take values from the input for use later in teh calculator

Comment: Use an array or two different methods, or potentially call the method twice.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return two values from a method. Instead, encapsulate your values inside a class and instantiate it.

```
public class Holder {
    private int first;
    private int second;
    // getters, setters, and constructors
}
```

Change your method accordingly

```
public static Holder getValues(int first, int second)
{
    first = Integer.parseInt(askQ("First Number"));
    second = Integer.parseInt(askQ("Second Number"));
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    holder.setFirst(first);
    holder.setSecond(second);

    return holder;
}
```

Note that java convention states that variable names should start with a lowercase character. Also, there is no point in passing  arguments to this method if you are just going to overwrite them. Get rid of your method parameters and declare them as local variables

```
public static Holder getValues()
{
    int first = Integer.parseInt(askQ("First Number"));
    int second = Integer.parseInt(askQ("Second Number"));
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    holder.setFirst(first);
    holder.setSecond(second);

    return holder;
}
```

Also, you should probably give a more meaningful name to the class and its fields, depending on your context.

Answer (score 0):

You should really just call the method twice:

```
public int getQuestionValue(String questionToAsk)
{
    answer = Integer.parseInt(askQ(questionToAsk));
    return answer;
}

//.... how to call it....

int answerOne = getQuestionValue("First Number");
int answerTwo = getQuestionValue("Second Number");
```